# Load file with javascript based on which button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple buttons that should each run the same bit of javascript. The only difference I want is which file to load from the button being clicked.

```
<button type="button" name="fileA.csv" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load File A</button>
<button type="button" name="fileB.csv" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load File B</button>
```

These 2 buttons should load the same bit of javascript code, but I want to use the buttons name attribute to choose which file

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#load_data').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url:"files/" + ATTRIBUTE_NAME,
    dataType:"text",
    success:function(data)

.... other code ....
```

where ATTRIBUTE_NAME is where I want the name attribute from the button press. Is there any way to do this?

EDIT
When I do $(this).attr(‘name’), it only does it for the first button

Comment: `$(this).attr('name')`

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this. I suggest doing some research on the jQuery documentation site; [perhaps their tutorial site has something for you](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/attributes/). A hint; there is a function called [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use nonstandard attributes like this. Use `data-name="fileA.csv"`, then use `$(this).data("name")`

Comment: You are not allowed to use same id for multiple elements. try selecting elements using class instead of id. `$(".btn-info1").click(function(){});` and `$(".btn-info2").click(function(){});`

Comment: But then wouldn’t I have to have the same function twice for the 2 classes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's exactly what you're looking for but you can put the entire code for the files in a function and use `onclick` attribute to execute it.
You could try looking into this:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_name.asp